# Increment column values based on two columns in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, function

I have a table Test , that has below structure:

```
Id  CID RO   Other Columns
1   111  2
2   111  1
3   111  6
4   111  6
5   111  8
6   111  5
7   101  4
8   101  4
9   101  3
```

Resultant order in RO should be like below:
-> For One CID and ascending order of RO should get order (RO) replaced with 1,2,3,4 and so on

Final Order in RO column:

(RO column's value got replaced)

```
 Id  CID RO  (New) RO Other Columns
    1   111  2   2
    2   111  1   1 
    3   111  6   4
    4   111  6   5
    5   111  8   6
    6   111  5   3
    7   101  4   2
    8   101  4   3
    9   101  3   1
```

There are hundreds of cids like that in table. Please let me know if this can be achieved in single query using some Oracle function or some procedure needs to be written. Any lead or example would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NEW_RO column can be calculated with the analytic function ROW_NUMBER():

```
select ... ,
       row_number() over (partition by cid order by ro) as new_ro  [, ...]
```

In your data, there are ties for RO within the same CID. Do you care, in that case, which row gets what NEW_RO value? If, for example, in the case of same RO you also want to (further) order by ID, you can change the above to

```
select ... ,
       row_number() over (partition by cid order by ro, id) as new_ro  [, ...]
```

**EDIT**:  I missed the fact that you need to UPDATE the RO values with the NEW_RO values. Analytic functions can't be used in an `UPDATE` statement (not directly anyway); the `MERGE` statement is the perfect alternative for this:

```
merge into test
  using ( select id, 
                 row_number() over (partition by cid order by ro, id) as new_ro 
          from   test
        ) s
        on (test.id = s.id)
when matched then update set ro = s.new_ro
;
```

Comment: this seems to be working.i do not need a new column new_ro and just want column 'RO' values to be replaced with new one. Is it possible to use update query with first query?

Comment: A trick is when you've got a query and want to update based on it is to use MERGE. I'll put an answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you , I am accepting your answer.I am not able to accept answers from both of you guys.Only one answer , I am able to select.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the follow up question in the comment on @mathguy's answer. If you've got a query that is producing the new values you want, and want to quickly write an update, I like to use merge:

```
MERGE INTO your_table target
USING (your_query_here) source
ON (Target.ID = Source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET Target.column = Source.new_value
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

MERGE can do more than that, but I've found it handy in this "correct the data" situation.